# How to optimally add columns to a table of large size?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, rdbms

I have a table with millions of rows of data. Now for some new incoming data, I have to store some more properties. Altering the table at this stage to create a new column would consume a lot of computing power because the table already has millions of rows of data. What is the most optimal way to store this new data if such new properties are added from time-to-time?

Edit: After a suggestion from a user, I wanted to add the platform that I am using: SnowFlake Cloud Data Platform.

Comment: its a one-time step.  If the "properties" make sense to be stored in that table, then add them there.  Also, you do need to tag with the proper database platform.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I have added the platform: SnowFlake. And with every ingestion, I might need to add an additional property and this will make the table too large with a lot of columns left mostly with NULL values. Is there a more elegant way to store this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry too much about the computing power needed to add columns - it's mostly a logical problem, not physical.

I did this test with an 8.4M rows table:

```sql
create table clone1
clone my_big_table;

alter table clone1
add column justtest NUMBER(38,0);

-- adding a column was a quick operation, just metadata probably (210ms)

create table lone2
clone my_big_table;

alter table clone2
add column justtest NUMBER(38,0) default 7;

-- adding a column with a default value was a quick operation too, just metadata probably (256ms)

select justtest
from clone2
limit 10;

-- correct data returned

create table clone3
clone my_big_table;

alter table clone3
add column justtest NUMBER(38,0) default 7;

-- again, adding a column with a default value was quick

update clone3
set justtest=1;

-- this took a longer time - changing an existing value for a new one (1min 18s)
```

Adding a column to a table shouldn't be a problem - just test the operation with a table clone before.

Comment: When you add a column (justtest) at the very beginning (210 ms), were all the values defaulted to NULL?

Comment: I think so, but just test it on your clone ;)